# Is there any solution to remove the macOS App - Prepare for Submission?

Tags: ios-appstore

As you can see I wanted to update my iOS App 2.2.0 to 2.2.1 but I accidentally added the macOS App.

[image]

After searching some solution on a couple website, I still can't find the solution...

Some say you can remove the "Prepare for Submission" in the "App Information" but I think that is not the correct way. I use that way, I think you will delete the whole App.

Even I wanted to try remove it but in the "App Information", I still can't see the "Remove" Button that I wanted... What can do I?

**Other's people screenshot:**

[image]

**My case:**

[image]

I even have go to the apple developer documentation have a look but their link is not working...(https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store-connect/)

All the link that I press in the apple documentation is just keep loading just like below this image.

[image]

**Is there any solution to remove the macOS App - Prepare for Submission?**

Comment: Also desperately looking for a way to remove this. It's incredibly annoying because on every page now (like Ratings and Reviews, Version History, etc) the default selection (top right) is "macOS App" so we have to toggle the dropdown to see the information for our iOS App.

Comment: Have u find a solution

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588140/456536), it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a new iOS App version (2.2.2 for instance), then you will see a red button near the "1.0 prepare for submission" message, and click on it to remove the macOS App.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to remove a version of your app in Prepare for Submission state.

You can provide feedback to Apple at [feedbackassistant.apple.com](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).

Comment: Is the feedback assistant really useful for developer-related questions like this?

Comment: @O'Rooney I usually link to the public feedback site, but for this question I’ve specifically linked to the feedback assistant instead as it’s the replacement bug tracker which developers get access to — it’s *more* useful than the usual feedback site.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Apple's Developer site](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev04f55d711):

> #### Remove a build from review
>
> To stop the App Review process, you can remove the app version from App Review. The app status must be one of the following to do this:
>
> - Waiting for Export Compliance
> - Waiting for Review
> - In Review
> - Pending Developer Release
> - Pending Apple Release
>
> Required role: Account Holder, Admin, or App Manager.
>
> 1. From My Apps, select your app. The page opens with the App Store tab selected.
> 2. In the sidebar, click the app version you want a build removed from review for.
> 3. In the message that appears up top, click “remove this version from review.”
>
>    [image]
> 4. In the dialog that appears, click Remove.
>
> The app version is removed from Apple’s review queue and the app status changes to Developer Rejected. Later, when you resubmit the app, the review process will start over from the beginning.

Comment: This is about removing a build from being reviewed, and the list of statuses it applies to does not include ‘Prepare for Submission’. Even if a build is submitted and then removed from review, the new version will still exist and be shown in the sidebar — there's no change.